# macOS - Finder separator in Sierra

Tags: macbook-pro, finder, macos

how can I separate these folders in macOS Sierra? About a week ago 'iCloud' and 'Desktop' folders were not in my favorites, but I was able to move them down. Yesterday I ran out of iCloud in my macbook and disappeared from that location. Do I get separated?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- From the Finder, select Finder->Preferences (or press CMD-,) to access Finder preferences.
- Click 'Sidebar' tab

[image]

There you can select which items appear in Favorites, Devices and other sections in the Finder sidebar. As far as I know you can't create additional separators within these sections, but you can drag/drop items in the sidebar to reorder them.